# print reddit scraping to file

Tags: python, reddit

I'd like to have the results of this query from Reddit to be redirected to a file.
thanks

```py
for comments in subreddit.stream.comments(skip_existing = True):
    if (time.time() - start_time) < 10:
        print(comments.body, comments.author)
```

Comment: Please go through a tutorial or two. This [topic](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) should be covered by any of the freely available tutorials.

Comment: I did, through more than one or two...sorry I had to resort to the forum...

Comment: "more than one or two" - I hope you did not mean those on youtube.

Comment: nope, I'll try harder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the only output of your file, `python myPythonFile.py > fileToWrite.txt` is the simplest solution in a shell environment.

Otherwise you can write to the file from Python:

```
# open the file
with open('fileToWrite', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f: 
    for comments in subreddit.stream.comments(skip_existing = True): 
        if (time.time() - start_time) < 10:
            f.write("{}, {}\n".format(comments.body, comments.author))
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it, almost, works but I get this error:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 61-62: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: I have edited my answer. UTF-8 encoding should fix this

Comment: yes! it did.. but for some reason the file is empty..

Comment: Sorry, we're good! I forgot to add the file's path...works perfectly now